# Asp.net using mvc application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-3.5

I have ASP.NET 3.5 version, which obliviously supports MVC application, ie. when we want to create a new MVC web application, we get the template in the asp.net file creation options.

My worry is , though I have asp.net 3.5 version , I could not see the ASP.NET MVC web application to create.

I referred the blog, in that someone has searched for 3.5 sp1 that doesn't support their MVC web application. I believe that this is not my relevant search.
And I hope I will get a solution for my query.

Comment: Your title is a little vague - could you expand it?  Something like "Could not find MVC template in..." or something similar?

Comment: You must install the MVC pack: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=215693

Comment: Yes, i could not see the mvc application template in my asp.net web templates....

Answer (score 1):

You may want to re-install your templates:

Open up visual studio command prompt and type:

devenv /installvstemplates

That should restore all your templates.

Comment: I will reinstall the templates and try ...thane for the response to all.

Comment: nothing is happening if i give "devenv /installvstemplates" this command

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using Visual Studio 2008.

Visual Studio 2008 supports ASP.NET MVC development up to versions ASP.NET MVC 1.0 an ASP.NET MVC 2.0. If you need to target later versions of ASP.NET MVC - you would need Visual Studio 2010/2012.

Visual Studio 2008 requires VisualStudio 2008 Service Pack 1 install. Plus ASP.NET MVC bundle installed for development.  ASP.NET MVC 2 provides a new Model-View-Controller (MVC) framework on top of the existing ASP.NET 3.5 SP1 runtime.

for Hosting Server you need .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 + ASP.NET MVC 2 RTM Runtime

Link to VS2008 SP1 - http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=13276
Link to ASP.NET MVC 2.0  http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=22079

hope that helps.

Comment: This product requires the Microsoft .NET 4 Framework. Please install the missing component, then try to install this product again.
This is Blocking issue that i faced when i run the exe of VS2008 SP1

Comment: Then your ASP.NET MVC solution is built on ASP.NET MVC 3.0 using Visual Studio 2010. Try opening it using VS2010.